# Dynamic V-model name in a v-for loop Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am developing an application and I am using `Vue 2` as the javascript framework, 
inside a `v-for` loop I need the counter of the loop to be bound to the `v-model` name of the elements, this my code:

```
<div v-for="n in total" class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_id" :name="'input_name_id['  + n  + ']'" v-model="form.parent_id_n" />
</div>
```

I need `n` to be the counter of the loop, for example for the first element it should be:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="input_id" :name="'input_name_id[1]" v-model="form.parent_id_1" />
</div>
```

the `name attribute` binding works but I have no idea how to get the `v-model` working as well?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To use `v-model` with `form.parent_id[n]`:

1. `form` should be a data property.
2. `form.parent_id` should be an array.

Then you can do the following:

```
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for='n in 3'>
    <input v-model="form.parent_id[n]">
  </div>
  <div v-for='n in 3'>
    {{ form.parent_id[n] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

by having a vue instance setup like:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      form: {
        parent_id: []
      }
    }
})
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujsqvo3x/) for a working example.

Comment: I don't get why 3 is used in v-for loop in the answer given

Comment: @TechPotter the 3 is not necessary. It was a quick example that I had typed out, maybe the same is used in the fiddle as an example (been a while since I answered) :)

Comment: As the total value range increases, the form.parent_id array length will increase . This is a drawback of this solution. Instead of 3, if the total starts from 100. The array will have 0-99 positions containing null values. A better solution is given by @mansur

Comment: How can I get the dynamic v-model inputs values now...?

Answer (score 19):

Another way achieve this is using bracket notation of accessing object property.

```
<div v-for="n in total" class="form-group">
   <input type="hidden" 
          id="input_id" 
          :name="'input_name_id['  + n  + ']'" 
          v-model="form['parent_id_' + n ]" />
</div>
```

Comment: How can I get the dynamic v-model inputs values now...?

Answer (score 18):

Repeated text filed 10 times and separated v-model for each

```
<v-text-field
  v-for="(n,index) in 10"
  :key="index"
  v-model="pricing.name[n]"
  color="info"
  outline
  validate-on-blur
/>
```

storing data

```
data() {
    return {
     pricing:{
      name: [],
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't get why this answer is not the preferred solution.. That is where the index is for right.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pick up these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

this code worked for me:

> HTML

```
<input type="number" @input="updateValue($event, i, 'pci')" :value="form.neighbours[i].pci" />
```

> JS

```
        updateValue(event, i, key) {
            const neighbour = {...this.form.neighbours[i]};
            neighbour[key] = event.target.value;
            this.form.neighbours.splice(i, 1, neighbour)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="appId">
  <!-- One way -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" v-for="n in 3">
      <input v-model="formFields.fieldName[n]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=row>
    <!-- For display -->
    <div class="col-lg-4" v-for="n in 3">
      {{formFields.fieldName[n]}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Two different way -->
  <div class="row" v-for="(val, index) in arrayName" :key="index">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        Start Date
        <input type="date" v-model="formSchema[val.start_date]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        End Date
        <input type="date" v-model="formSchema[val.end_date]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        Details
        <textarea v-model="formSchema[val.details]"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- For display -->
  {{formSchema.link_to_start_date}} {{formSchema.link_to_end_date}}
</div>
 
var appId = new Vue({
  el: '#appId',
  data: {
    //For One way
    formFields:{
      fieldName:[
        'name','address','phone_number'
      ],
    },
    
    //For different way 
    formSchema:{
      link_to_start_date:'',
      link_to_end_date:'',
      link_to_details:'',
      tap_start_date:'',
      tap_end_date:'',
      tap_details:'',
    },

    arrayName:[
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Link to breaking down your assignment question workshop1',
        start_date :'link_to_start_date',
        end_date :'link_to_end_date',
        details :'link_to_details',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Link to breaking down your assignment question workshop2',
        start_date :'tap_start_date',
        end_date :'tap_end_date',
        details :'tap_details',
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In VueJS3 with TypeScript is like this...

```
<script lang="ts" setup>

const options = ref<string[]>([])
const comments = ref<string[]>([])
```

In the Component view

```
<VCol
        v-for="feature in features"
        :key="feature.id"
        cols="12"
      >
        <VRow>
          <!--  Each Feature -->
          <VCol
            cols="12"
            md="3"
            class="d-flex align-items-center"
          >
            <label
              class="v-label text-high-emphasis"
              :for="`feature-${feature.id}`"
            >{{ feature.name }}</label>
          </VCol>

          <VCol
            cols="12"
            md="2"
            class="d-flex align-items-center"
          >
            <VSelect
              v-model="options[feature.id]"
              class="v-label text-high-emphasis"
              :items="feature.options"
              item-title="option"
              item-value="id"
            />
          </VCol>

          <VCol
            cols="12"
            md="4"
          >
            <AppTextField
              :id="`feature-${feature.id}`"
              v-model="comments[feature.id]"
              :placeholder="`Comments for ${feature.name}`"
              persistent-placeholder
            />
          </VCol>

          <VCol
            cols="12"
            md="3"
          >
            <VFileInput
              multiple
              chips
              label="Files"
            />
          </VCol>
        </VRow>
      </VCol>
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming `input_name_id` is a string, What you need to do is `:name="'input_name_id' + n"`

Here is a working [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dspoonia7/d9f9tj4n/4/)

Comment: How can I get the dynamic v-model inputs values now...?

Comment: It is not clear how it work and nothing is change in example.