# Vue - Array push within an array push

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to achieve adding different `rows` for each `genres` array push. The problem is all the `rows` are simultaneously added for each `genre` and if I input the text, it will reflect in all `rows`. How do I separate the entity of each `rows`?

Here is my code.

**Template**

```
<table class="table">
  <v-btn @click="addGenre()">Add Genre</v-btn>

  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="genre in genres" :key="genre.id">
     <td>

       <v-select/>
       <v-btn @click="addRow()">Add Row</v-btn> // add row for each genre added

       <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.id">
         <td><v-textarea/></td>
       </tr>

     </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>

export default {
  data: ()=> ({
    genres: [],
    rows: [],
  }),

methods: {
  addGenre () {
    this.genres.push({
     genre: '',
    });
  },

  addRow () {
    this.rows.push({
      row: '',
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: you have to used Dynamic V-model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364487/dynamic-v-model-name-in-a-v-for-loop-vue-2

Comment: I'll check this out, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue, I think you should just store rows inside of the genre objects.

```
<tr v-for="(genre, genreIndex) in genres" :key="genre.id">
     <td>
       <v-select/>
       <v-btn @click="addRow(genreIndex)">Add Row</v-btn> // add row for each genre added
       <tr v-for="(row, index) in genre.rows" :key="row.id">
         <td><v-textarea v-model="row.row"/></td>
       </tr>
     </td>
</tr>
```

```
  data: ()=> ({
    genres: [],
  }),
```

```
methods: {
  addGenre () {
    this.genres.push({
     genre: '',
     rows: [],
    });
  },

  addRow (genreIndex) {
    this.genres[genreIndex].rows.push({
      row: '',
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: No problem my dude

Comment: May I please have a follow-up question? I'm having errors when adding a row when data are displayed `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"` `this.genres = response.data` since index are not called, unlike when pressing the `addGenre()` function.