# Insert an element into template but no v-model

Tags: vue.js

use vue
i want to insert an element when i click createItem:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-row group">
    <h5 class="p-2 col-md-12">item</h5>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Num" v-model="tempitemNum">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1" @click="createItem">create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="items col-md-12 mt-1 mb-1">
      //create item here
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my script function

```
createItem: function(){
    let items = document.querySelector('.items');
    if(this.itemNum == 0){
        this.itemNum = parseInt(this.tempitemNum);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.itemNum; i++) {
            let item = document.createElement('div');
            item.className = "col-md-12 mb-1 pl-0 pr-0";
            item.innerHTML = `
            <div>
                <span>${i+1}.</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            `
            items.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", item);
        }}}
```

how can i insert item with v-model in every input element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic V-model name in a v-for loop Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364487/dynamic-v-model-name-in-a-v-for-loop-vue-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsx to render Dom elements and now you can use v-model with it you can check: https://github.com/nickmessing/babel-plugin-jsx-v-model