# How do I get values from multiple vue select instances?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for, v-model

I have 2 arrays of objects like below. I need to create a select for every `questions` element, and I need to have the options connected with the `selections` by the id. In this case I need to have 2 selects, the first one will have `1000`, `5000` and `10000` as options meanwhile the second select will have `yes` and `no` as options

```js
const questions = [{
        'id': 1,
        'question': 'KM'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'question': 'Works'
    }
]

const selections = [{
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 1000
    },
    {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 5000
    },
    {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 10000
    },
    {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'yes'
    },
    {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'no'
    }
]
```

I made it like this in vue but the issue is that I can't save the data in the v-model as I'm returning the values from `cars()` and not a variable specified in `data()`

```html
<div class="form-group" v-for="item in questions" v-bind:key="item.question">
    <h5 v-if="showQuestion(item.id)">{{ item.question }}</h5>

    <div class="tour-options-select" v-if="showQuestion(item.id)">
        <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" class="tour-options-dropdown" v-model="questions.value">
            <option v-for="item1 in cars(item.id)" v-bind:key="item1.id" :value="item1.display_name">{{ item1.display_name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I just need to know, how do I get the value when I have a structure like the one I defined above?

Comment: Related: [Dynamic V-model name in a v-for loop Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43364487/11047824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array in `data()` to store your selected options, you can use `v-model` to dynamically bind with an element in that array if you give it an index:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions: [{
        'id': 1,
        'question': 'KM'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'question': 'Works'
      }
    ],
    selections: [{
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 1000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 5000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 10000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'yes'
      },
      {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'no'
      }
    ],
    selected: [],
  },
  methods: {
    cars: function(id) {
      return this.selections.reduce((arr, currSel) => {
        if (currSel.question_id == id)
          arr.push(currSel);
        return arr;
      }, []);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in questions" :name="question.question" :key="question.id">
    <select v-model="selected[index]">
      <option v-for="option in cars(question.id)" :key="option.question_id" :value="option.value">
        {{ option.value }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <p>Selected:</p>
  <pre>{{ $data.selected }}</pre>
</div>
```

Another approach would be to use *events* to handle the changes, calling a custom function each time the user makes a selection, eg using `@change`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions: [{
        'id': 1,
        'question': 'KM'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'question': 'Works'
      }
    ],
    selections: [{
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 1000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 5000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 1,
        'value': 10000
      },
      {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'yes'
      },
      {
        'question_id': 2,
        'value': 'no'
      }
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    cars: function(id) {
      return this.selections.reduce((arr, currSel) => {
        if (currSel.question_id == id)
          arr.push(currSel);
        return arr;
      }, []);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(question, index) in questions" :name="question.question" :key="question.id">
    <select @change="console.log('Option', $event.target.value, 'chosen for Q', question.id)">
      <option selected disabled>Select...</option>
      <option v-for="option in cars(question.id)" :key="option.question_id" :value="option.value">
        {{ option.value }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way will give you more freedom to store or process the data as you wish, but you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: You are a beast! Thank you