# Nested loop to v-model Vue JS

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, v-for, v-model

I want to collect the data from input with v-model on nested loop, but idk how to do it cause i'm new in Vue.
Here's the code for the component :

```
        <div
            class="date-item"
            v-for="(day,index) in dateList"
        >
          <div class="mt-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <ul class="list-task">
                <li v-for="(n,n_key) in 10" :key="n_key">
                  <base-input
                      :id="'input-text'+n"
                      :type="'text'"
                      :disabled="day.isPastDay"
                  />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Anyone can help how i created a v-model and data variable for this case ?

Comment: `in 10` is not a model, what are you trying to bind to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364487/dynamic-v-model-name-in-a-v-for-loop-vue-2
this would help

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i'm still trying to collect data from each input

Comment: @DeepinderSingh thanks, but mine is have 2 loop for the input, so it just change the entire of 10 inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `v-model="day.inputs[n_key]"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dateList: [{
      isPastDay: false,
      inputs: []
    }]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="date-item" v-for="(day,index) in dateList">
    <div class="mt-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="list-task">
          <li v-for="(n,n_key) in 10" :key="n_key">
            <input type="text" v-model="day.inputs[n_key]" :disabled="day.isPastDay" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <pre>{{ dateList }}</pre>
</div>
```